# Javascript setting a variable that is concatenated by a string and another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to using Javascript and I have run into this problem that I am sure is an easy fix with the right syntax.

I have a variable (totalRow1) that I have declared. I need to set that variable later but it needs to be concatenated with a string and the value of another variable (currentCardRow).

```
var totalRow1;
var currentCardRow = 1;

 function calculateRow(){ 

 "totalRow" + currentCardRow = 50;

 }
```

Thanks your all your help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is wrapped in a function and I am trying to set a variable that is outside of it. Would this change things?

Comment: if totalRow1 is a global variable.. you can use..  `window["totalRow" + currentCardRow]`

Answer (score 0):

```
this["totalRow" + currentCardRow] = 50;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately its not working for me. I forgot to mention that this is wrapped in a function and I am trying to set a variable that is outside of it. Would this change things?